# Blocking a website

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dns, hosts

I need to block a particular website on my Mac (OSX 10.11.1, El Capitan).
I have already made the changes to /etc/hosts but the website is still not blocked when testing from Chrome.  I think this has to do with it being an HTTPS connection.

Procedure:

Using `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, I have modified the /etc/hosts file to add the following lines:

`0.0.0.0    goodreads.com
0.0.0.0    176.32.103.85`

I checked the changes with `cat /etc/hosts`.  Then I flushed the DNS cache using `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` and `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`.
I then try to access the page from within Chrome and it succeeds.  I have also rebooted the machine, but the connection still succeeds.

It seems that this should work.   I have searched extensively, and this approach is the most recommended.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following hosts file entries:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       goodreads.com www.goodreads.com www1.goodreads.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

To properly block websites with the hosts file you also have to include aliases like www, ww1, www1, mail etc.

Comment: Confirmed.  When I added the www. to the domain name the website was blocked.  Many thanks!